# Web-Shiro PassThruAuthenticationFilter not working

Tags: java, jsf, shiro

I was trying to follow [this tutorial](http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2012/12/29/using-apache-shiro-with-jsf.html) about how to secure a jsf-page with apache shiro.

My question is:
Even if i configure in my shiro.ini file, that the protected jsf-page has to be authenticated, I can still access it with the url to it and without authenticating.

My shiro.ini file:

```
[main]
authc.loginUrl = /login.xhtml
authc = org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.PassThruAuthenticationFilter
securityManager.rememberMeManager.cookie.name = demoRememberMe

[users]
admin = secret

[roles]
admin = *

[urls]
/index.xhtml = anon
/protected.xhtml = authc
```

[image: My web-resources folder]

Comment: How You get +2 votes while total number of view including me and u is 4?

Comment: @BalusC Then which category we should fall?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi two of my colleagues are also interested in this problem

Comment: @BalusC could you get a little bit more concrete, i am new to apache shiro.

Comment: 3 other collegues to? Are you not able to come up with more (debug) info, like is the filter called, is shiro called, filter order etc